# How do I undo Data Cloud Account mapping?

Tags: salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

I am trying to undo Account mapping in Data Cloud, I have removed all field mappings, all segments and everything I could delete, however, I still see an error when I try to delete Account data stream or Account data lake object.

I can see that there are some Data Model Object dependencies on the error
[image]

however, I can't remove them since they are inactive and do not allow the removal, the trash icon is inactive.
[image]

How should I resolve this?

Comment: this is totally irrelevant. But can you please let me know you got a trial org for data cloud or is this your company's org?

Comment: participating in PLC workshop

Comment: when you start PLC Data Cloud 11 courses, in the third course you have the link to request a trial Data Cloud org for 90 days for performing PLC 11 courses hands-on activities

Comment: More info can be found here: https://sfdc.co/DCCurriculum and here: https://quip.com/0k29AxC34DiT. Maybe I should post this as a separate question and answer

Comment: @NagendraSingh https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/408587/how-can-i-get-a-data-cloud-trial-org/408588#408588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had to go to Data Model objects and switch to 'All' view, since the default view is mapped and it doesn't show Account - Latest, Account - Profiles and Account - History data model objects.
[image]

Once I switch to 'All' view, I can see and delete Account - Latest, Account - Profiles and Account - History data model objects and after that delete Account Data Stream, delete it from Data Space

[image]