# How can I get a data cloud trial org?

Tags: salesforce-cdp, datacloud, cdp

I would like to learn Data Cloud and receive hands-on experience. How can I access or get a Data Cloud trial org for training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Data Cloud curriculum in PLC https://sfdc.co/DCCurriculum which consists of 11 courses and in the 3rd course there is a form to fill out to request Data Cloud Trial org for 90 days.

Assuming you are Salesforce Partner or work for Salesforce Partner then you can apply for this course and receive a Data Cloud trial org.

There is an additional Get Skilled up for Data Cloud Implementations Program https://quip.com/0k29AxC34DiT held in both EMEA/AMER and APAC timezones with lectures and office hours to answer questions held from Aug 1st 2023 - Sep 7th 2023.

---

Update (Effective 8 Dec 2023)

Data Cloud Trial Orgs are now available via Partner Learning Camp (Demo Org tab - https://partnerlearningcamp.salesforce.com/s/demo-org)

Please use Demo Type of DCDO (Data Cloud Demo Org) to request your 30 day Trial org via PLC (see screenshot below)

In order for that tab to be visible you must complete the ‘Simple Demo Org Fundamentals’ course.

(See details here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000391924&type=1)

Note: The Data Cloud Trial Orgs are still dictated by the Rules of Engagement outlined here - https://sfdc.co/dctrialorgroe

Comment: Hi @Patlatus so basically for someone to learn data cloud , partner community access is a must? Is there no other way to have a free dev edition org enabled with data cloud. Please guide.

Comment: I think now is it available under SDO

Answer (score 0):

Update from TDX 24 - you can now sign up for a Developer Edition with Data Cloud - it only lasts for 5 days, but anyone can sign up - more details here:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/create-a-data-stream-in-data-cloud/get-started-with-a-data-cloud-developer-edition